# Is there any way for a player character to get Threatening Reach?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

Is there anyway for a player character to get the `Threatening Reach` or equivalent ability with a reach weapon?

Apart for one-off's like artifacts such as the **Spear of Urrok the Brave** <sup>[[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=119)]</sup>

Comment: Do you have any parameters or restrictions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pure threatening reach does not exist as an always on thing.

However, there are a number of close approximations.

From earliest level we get:

- [Fire Hawk](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=9634) Druid 1 at-will ([FAQ](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1905))

  - As strategies goes, if you hit with this, if the target takes an action that will provoke, you hit again. It is one of the best approximations of threatening reach out there, given that it's range 10. It can be enhanced in all of the usual ways.
- Lightning Rush Battlemind 7

  - It's not "if you get close to me you get punished" but it is "If you attack an ally within 5, I'll whack you" which has some of the essence of threatening reach.
- Polearm Gamble

  - Part of the standard polearm momentum package. It doesn't prevent casters 2 squares away from you casting, but it's close enough.
- Repel Charge

  - MBA when people charge you. Again, edge case (but different edge case than gamble)
- Stoneblessed Goliath PP

  - Level 12 Summit Advantage provides it for a turn.
- [Polearm Master](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=166) Fighter PP

  - > Longarm Grasp (16th level): If you’re wielding a reach weapon, whenever an enemy within 2 squares of you and marked by you shifts or makes an attack that doesn’t include you as a target, you can make a melee basic attack against that enemy as an immediate interrupt.
  - It's not *quite* threatening reach... but it's close enough. Especially if you build a knight.
- Form of the Primal Beast

  - Level 20 daily, but it does explicitly give you threatening reach.
- Foe Caller Gauntlets

  - Level 22 Item that is a /1enc ranged punish

Comment: Also 'Summit Advantage', a utility 12 power for the Goliath Racial Paragon 'Stoneblessed' path. Read: "until the end of your next turn, you have threatening reach."

Comment: The other answer here could be added into yours

Answer (score 2):

Spiked Chain Expert (Multiclass feat) 8th level
Lets you swap out for Chain ward a daily power that gives you a threatening reach stance.