# Goring Charge Monk Optimization

Tags: dnd-4e, charge

So I have been thinking about creating a minotaur monk character. I looked at feats and skills so I could get some general idea where to aim with the build.
This particular combination caught my eye.

Does this build grant basically melee invulnerability?

Minotaur with *opportunity gore*, *reach 2* weapon (the only such weapon I managed to find is the *spear of Urruk the Brave*), *boots of adept charging* and *badge of the berserker* for good measure.

Now lets assume that I have no enemies within 2 squares (in my reach).

If enemy wanted to engage me in melee combat, could I just use my opportunity attack the moment he enters the *threatening reach 2* radius and use my OA on him. 
Having the *opportunity gore* feat, I would instead use *gore charge* and knocked the enemy prone. Then using my boots I would shift back to the original position, with enemy knocked down and me safely away from him.

Repeating this tactics on any enemy who would want to attack me would prevent anyone from even touching me with a melee attack for as long as I could land my goring charge OA.

Is this strategy legit?

Also: when would the goring charge OA resolve? Would I attack the enemy on the square where he entered my threatening reach area or on the square adjacent to me? (In the second case I could just get second feat goring shove to throw him one square away, effectively blocking any attempts to escape my reach when not shifting first.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This does not work.**

First:

The opportunity attack *interrupts* the movement, so the enemy is still 2 squares away from you. Goring Charge is not an option as it is a melee 1 power (2 things here, it's not a weapon power, so no reach even with a reach weapon, it also specifies melee 1, rather than melee, so it's not modifiable with a reach weapon). Plus the power is not a weapon power and the weapon grants the threatening reach.

Second:

If you use Goring Charge as an attack of Opportunity, you are using it as an opportunity action *instead* of on a charge (the feat text says to ignore the effect), so the Boots of Adept Charging don't get used here.

Lastly:

Even if this was possible, it's predicated on an item that *you don't want to plan on getting*. It's not one you can start with (its an artifact), and it's not one you can keep (artifacts move on). Don't build strategy around these items. [Threatening reach is *very, very* hard to get for a normal character](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14308/1084).

That said, if you have *some other way* of proning on an opportunity attack, yeah you can stop an enemy from moving into you. You might be interested in the Polearm Momentum/Gamble combo for a similar effect. It is mentioned in the link above.

So no. This power combination will not work the way you're thinking it will.

Comment: I am a bit confused regarding the Opportunity gore. It says I should ignore the power's requirement(which would be the charge part in this case?) and action type (standard action) and then use it in place of the standard melee attack. (So this would be the attack part of the goring charge). The melee 1 is not a requirement then?

Comment: @pppddd the melee 1 is still very much in force. The requirement in this case is the Effect line (opportunity Gore seems badly worded to me, but that is the only requirement in the power). The powers range (melee 1) is still in effect AFAICT

Comment: Thanks, the wording is rather wierd indeed because if the effect line would work, then I would have to make the charge part as well (so move 2+ squares towards the enemy) which would make this feat useless since it could not be done in melee range (when used normally). Right?

Comment: exactly. Even in this case, a charge isn't valid as you must move 2 squares before the attack.

Answer (score 3):

**Even if you can make it work, it won't work for long**

You are relying on opportunity attacks in order to keep your foes at bay. An intelligent opponent, who has identified this as a tactic will adapt their own tactics and charge you on your own turn.

How? By readying an action.

An opponent could ready a charge against you with a trigger of "The monk minotaur starts its turn", and since you cannot take opportunity actions on your own turn, they will slip past your defence.

Note, that this is a good trick for your own arsenal if you are fighting an enemy with a movement halting threatening reach attack.